# Installing binding_of_caller 0.7.2 with native extensions failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, makefile, rubygems

Trying my hand at Ruby on Rails.  Sorry if this is a little rudimentary. I am trying to understand why this is happening. If you can help, thanks a ton!

I am trying to create a project for Rails

in cmd line I input:
C:\Users\Player 1\Sites>rails new simple_cms -d mysql

I get the error at this point:

Installing binding_of_caller 0.7.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151020-6164-22d8zu.rb extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing binding_of_caller (0.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.7.2'` succeeds before
bundling.